# ASP.NET C# EF - How to benefit the full object after selecting it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I've been working on ASP.NET C# with Entity Framework and some people help me very much on certain key points.

There also one point I could not understand fully. Aren't we supposed to use the object and its subobjects (foreign key relation table data) when we retrieve the data from EF?

Here is my database design (which was also displayed in my previously answered question)
[image]

In my code, I simply get Member entity like this:

```
//In some aspx.cs file
var Mem = new MemberManager().GetById(2);

//In MemberManager class
public Member GetById(long id)
        {
            using(var Context = new NoxonEntities())
            {
                return Context.Member.First(c => c.Id == id);
            }
        }
```

When I do this:

```
var Mem = new MemberManager().GetById(2);
var Lang = Mem.Language;
//I get 
//Error: 'Mem.Language' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'
```

In order to get rid of this exception I needed to do this:

```
public Member GetById(long id)
        {
            using(var Context = new NoxonEntities())
            {
                var Result = Context.Member.First(c => c.Id == id);
                //Getting the Language Entity
                Result.Language = Context.Language.First(c => c.Id == Result.LanguageId);

                return Result;
            }
        }
```

Do I have to run a SELECT in order to have **FULL** entity? What if there were **ANOTHER** related table to Language table lets say *Feature* Table. Should I do this:

```
public Member GetById(long id)
            {
                using(var Context = new NoxonEntities())
                {
                    var Result = Context.Member.First(c => c.Id == id);
                    //Getting the Language Entity
                    Result.Language = Context.Language.First(c => c.Id == Result.LanguageId);
                    Result.Language.Feature = Context.Language.Feature.First(c => c.Id == Result.FeatureId);
                    return Result;
                }
            }
```

Which could go verrry long and
I'm pretty sure (at least I genuinely hope) I am wrong about something, but if we cannot use the object and its subobjects **AFTER** selecting, what is the purpose of having EF? Can we only use the subobjects in site the `using(var Context = new NoxonEntities())` block?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the context as a database connection. You make this connection available to you when you create the context in the `using` statement and throw it away at the end of the `using`. Everything after the `using` block cannot access the database connection anymore. You get an exception here...

```
var Lang = Mem.Language;
```

...because *lazy loading* tries to load the `Language` navigation property from the database, but the connection to the database is already disposed. You can use such a lazy loading only *within* your `using` block when the connection to the database is still available.

You can simplify loading the navigation properties in your example by using *eager loading* with `Include`:

```
public Member GetById(long id)
{
    using(var Context = new NoxonEntities())
    {
        return Context.Member.Include("Language").First(c => c.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Or for both navigation properties use:

```
return Context.Member.Include("Language.Feature").First(c => c.Id == id);
```

It will load the member *and* the language and feature in one single database query.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is due to Lazy Loading.  What's happening is that EF isn't loading your related entity `Language` because it's not sure it's going to need the data. Then, you're disposing the context so when you attempt to access the `Language` navigation property it's unable to make the jump.

You have a few options here.  You can eager load, here's a great [blog post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232) on eager loading, the Language entity:

```
var Result = Context.Member.Include("Language").First(c => c.Id == id);
```

Or, you need to keep the context alive throughout the entire request. Here's a [good post on a great method to keeping your context alive for each request](http://www.blog.cyberkinetx.com/2011/05/15/entity-framework-context-per-request/).

I do remember you're other post though - and I believe you're detaching your entity and storing it somewhere else, then re attaching.  If this is related to that functionality, then accessing your Language object, **after** you re attach it to a context will also fix your problem.